# Loop json variable in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I have a variable in which I get `json` value. The value comes from 4 tables. I want to loop each table while assigning values. Below is my code

```
var dataResponse = JSON.parse(response);
```

I get values from table as

`dataResponse.Table[0]` , `dataResponse.Table[1]` ....

how to loop it in javascript. Please help

My `json` value

```
{
  "Table": [{
    "JOB_PROGRESS_ID": 4.0,
    "SPAN_ID": "MUMUMBMUKLYNSPN001_BU",
    "LINK_ID": "12345678",
    "SPAN_TYPE": "INTERCITY",
    "NE_SPAN_LENGTH": 200.0,
    "HOTO_OFFERED_LENGTH": 26.0,
    "LIT_OFFERED_LENGTH": 30.0,
    "HOTO_ACTUAL_LENGTH": 20.0,
    "LIT_ACTUAL_LENGTH": 15.0,
    "HOTO_OFFERED_DATE": null,
    "HOTO_ACCEPTENCE_DATE": null,
    "LIT_ACCEPTENCE_DATE": null,
    "APPROV_REJECT_REMARK": null,
    "ISABDMISSING": 1.0,
    "JOB_ID": 1.0,
    "MAINTENANCEZONECODE": "INMUKLYN01"
  }],
  "Table1": [{
    "NUMBEROFDUCTS": 3,
    "ROUTETYPE": "HDD",
    "ASBUILT_LENGTH": 0.09,
    "SPAN_ID": "MUMUMBMUKLYNSPN001_BU"
  }, {
    "NUMBEROFDUCTS": 3,
    "ROUTETYPE": null,
    "ASBUILT_LENGTH": 0.33,
    "SPAN_ID": "MUMUMBMUKLYNSPN001_BU"
  }, {
    "NUMBEROFDUCTS": 7,
    "ROUTETYPE": "OT",
    "ASBUILT_LENGTH": 12.41,
    "SPAN_ID": "MUMUMBMUKLYNSPN001_BU"
  }, {
    "NUMBEROFDUCTS": 3,
    "ROUTETYPE": "OT",
    "ASBUILT_LENGTH": 0.01,
    "SPAN_ID": "MUMUMBMUKLYNSPN001_BU"
  }, {
    "NUMBEROFDUCTS": 7,
    "ROUTETYPE": "HDD",
    "ASBUILT_LENGTH": 0.46,
    "SPAN_ID": "MUMUMBMUKLYNSPN001_BU"
  }, {
    "NUMBEROFDUCTS": 8,
    "ROUTETYPE": "HDD",
    "ASBUILT_LENGTH": 0.02,
    "SPAN_ID": "MUMUMBMUKLYNSPN001_BU"
  }, {
    "NUMBEROFDUCTS": 6,
    "ROUTETYPE": "OT",
    "ASBUILT_LENGTH": 0.33,
    "SPAN_ID": "MUMUMBMUKLYNSPN001_BU"
  }, {
    "NUMBEROFDUCTS": 7,
    "ROUTETYPE": "CLAMP",
    "ASBUILT_LENGTH": 0.48,
    "SPAN_ID": "MUMUMBMUKLYNSPN001_BU"
  }, {
    "NUMBEROFDUCTS": 5,
    "ROUTETYPE": "OT",
    "ASBUILT_LENGTH": 0.14,
    "SPAN_ID": "MUMUMBMUKLYNSPN001_BU"
  }, {
    "NUMBEROFDUCTS": 8,
    "ROUTETYPE": "OT",
    "ASBUILT_LENGTH": 5.45,
    "SPAN_ID": "MUMUMBMUKLYNSPN001_BU"
  }, {
    "NUMBEROFDUCTS": null,
    "ROUTETYPE": "OT",
    "ASBUILT_LENGTH": 0.23,
    "SPAN_ID": "MUMUMBMUKLYNSPN001_BU"
  }],
  "Table2": [],
  "Table3": [{
    "UMS_GROUP_ASS_BY_NAME": "Construction_Eng",
    "MODIFIED_BY": "HARDIK1.SHAH",
    "MODIFIED_DATE": "2017-11-27T12:07:39",
    "APPROVED_DATE": null,
    "REJECTED_DATE": null
  }, {
    "UMS_GROUP_ASS_BY_NAME": "Construction_Eng",
    "MODIFIED_BY": "HARDIK1.SHAH",
    "MODIFIED_DATE": "2017-11-27T12:07:39",
    "APPROVED_DATE": null,
    "REJECTED_DATE": null
  }, {
    "UMS_GROUP_ASS_BY_NAME": "Construction_Eng",
    "MODIFIED_BY": "HARDIK1.SHAH",
    "MODIFIED_DATE": "2017-11-27T12:07:39",
    "APPROVED_DATE": null,
    "REJECTED_DATE": null
  }, {
    "UMS_GROUP_ASS_BY_NAME": "Construction_Eng",
    "MODIFIED_BY": "HARDIK1.SHAH",
    "MODIFIED_DATE": "2017-11-27T12:07:39",
    "APPROVED_DATE": null,
    "REJECTED_DATE": null
  }, {
    "UMS_GROUP_ASS_BY_NAME": "Construction_Eng",
    "MODIFIED_BY": "HARDIK1.SHAH",
    "MODIFIED_DATE": "2017-11-27T12:07:39",
    "APPROVED_DATE": null,
    "REJECTED_DATE": null
  }, {
    "UMS_GROUP_ASS_BY_NAME": "Construction_Eng",
    "MODIFIED_BY": "HARDIK1.SHAH",
    "MODIFIED_DATE": "2017-11-27T12:07:39",
    "APPROVED_DATE": null,
    "REJECTED_DATE": null
  }, {
    "UMS_GROUP_ASS_BY_NAME": "Construction_Eng",
    "MODIFIED_BY": "HARDIK1.SHAH",
    "MODIFIED_DATE": "2017-11-27T12:07:39",
    "APPROVED_DATE": null,
    "REJECTED_DATE": null
  }]
}
```

**UPDATE**

```
var dataResponse = JSON.parse(response);

for (var i = 0; i < dataResponse.Table.length; i++) {
  if (dataResponse.Table[i] != "" || dataResponse.Table[i] != null) {
    $("#spnLinkId").text(dataResponse.Table[i].LINK_ID);
    $("#spnSpanLength").text(dataResponse.Table[i].NE_SPAN_LENGTH);
    $("#txtFiberActlength").val(dataResponse.Table[i].HOTO_ACTUAL_LENGTH);
    $("#txtLITActlength").val(dataResponse.Table[i].LIT_ACTUAL_LENGTH);
  }
  if (dataResponse.Table[i].ISABDMISSING != "" || dataResponse.Table[i].ISABDMISSING != null) {

    if (dataResponse.Table[i].ISABDMISSING == 1) {
      $("#FEmissingAsBuiltYes").prop("checked", true);
    } else {
      $("#FEmissingAsBuiltNo").prop("checked", true);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: for(var i =0;i<=dataResponse.Table.length;i++){
var val = dataResponse.Table[i]; // use the val variable to get the values
}

Comment: @VinodkumarG: will it work properly if any of the table does not have any data ?

Comment: yes, it will work, because you will be taking any particular property or value in table or just add a condition to check if IsNullOrEmply check or if(val) // only if value exist it will go inside the loop

Comment: @VinodkumarG: I have updated my question with what I have done, do let me know if i am correct or not.. or I have to make any changes

Comment: Yes few modification,, just add a condition to check if the property is present or not,, like if(dataResponse.Table[i].LINK_ID) {$("#spnLinkId").text(dataResponse.Table[i].LINK_ID);} same for all other properties. only if the property is present it will assign to the selector or it wouldn,t

Comment: @VinodkumarG: can u update this as an answer

Comment: Don't use an if statement to set a boolean value...  just use the value.. eg `$("#FEmissingAsBuiltYes").prop("checked", dataResponse.Table[i].ISABDMISSING == 1);`

Comment: @ErikPhilips: Sure sir, will do that too.. I was confused on looping part. guessing which one is the correct one.

Answer (score 1):

Oh my... Your `dataResponse.Table` is not an `Array`. It is an `Object`.

For `Array` of array-like object, you use [for loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for).

However, to loop an `Object`, you use [for...in loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in).

In your case, it can be done so like:

```
for (var key in dataResponse){
    /* Your logic here */
    /* key => Table, Table1, Table2... */
    /* dataResponse[key] => [{...}], [{...}]... */
}
```

I will not answer your question directly. Because clearly you have not make any notable effort in researching looping in javascript.

Comment: @ErikPhilips OP wants to loop `dataResponse`

Comment: got it, let me try and check :)

Comment: i didn't get this `dataResponse[key] => [{...}], [{...}]... *` ?

Comment: i tried like this `dataResponse.key.LINK_ID` but it is coming as undefined. pls suggest what is the correct way to use

Answer (score 0):

The response is an **object** not an **array**.
For iterating over an object, we use **for-in** loop and 
for iterating over an array, we use **for** loop.
In your case, you use for-in loop.

```
for(var item in dataResponse){
//logic
}
```

Comment: The response is a JSON object { } not an array [].
var obj = {firstname:'James',lastname:'John'}.This is an object as it is in your case(within { }).To iterate over it we use for in loop.

Answer (score -1):

```js
var dataResponse = {
  "Table": [{
    "JOB_PROGRESS_ID": 4.0,
    "SPAN_ID": "MUMUMBMUKLYNSPN001_BU",
    "LINK_ID": "12345678",
    "SPAN_TYPE": "INTERCITY",
    "NE_SPAN_LENGTH": 200.0,
    "HOTO_OFFERED_LENGTH": 26.0,
    "LIT_OFFERED_LENGTH": 30.0,
    "HOTO_ACTUAL_LENGTH": 20.0,
    "LIT_ACTUAL_LENGTH": 15.0,
    "HOTO_OFFERED_DATE": null,
    "HOTO_ACCEPTENCE_DATE": null,
    "LIT_ACCEPTENCE_DATE": null,
    "APPROV_REJECT_REMARK": null,
    "ISABDMISSING": 1.0,
    "JOB_ID": 1.0,
    "MAINTENANCEZONECODE": "INMUKLYN01"
  }],
  "Table1": [{
    "NUMBEROFDUCTS": 3,
    "ROUTETYPE": "HDD",
    "ASBUILT_LENGTH": 0.09,
    "SPAN_ID": "MUMUMBMUKLYNSPN001_BU"
  }, {
    "NUMBEROFDUCTS": 3,
    "ROUTETYPE": null,
    "ASBUILT_LENGTH": 0.33,
    "SPAN_ID": "MUMUMBMUKLYNSPN001_BU"
  }, {
    "NUMBEROFDUCTS": 7,
    "ROUTETYPE": "OT",
    "ASBUILT_LENGTH": 12.41,
    "SPAN_ID": "MUMUMBMUKLYNSPN001_BU"
  }, {
    "NUMBEROFDUCTS": 3,
    "ROUTETYPE": "OT",
    "ASBUILT_LENGTH": 0.01,
    "SPAN_ID": "MUMUMBMUKLYNSPN001_BU"
  }, {
    "NUMBEROFDUCTS": 7,
    "ROUTETYPE": "HDD",
    "ASBUILT_LENGTH": 0.46,
    "SPAN_ID": "MUMUMBMUKLYNSPN001_BU"
  }, {
    "NUMBEROFDUCTS": 8,
    "ROUTETYPE": "HDD",
    "ASBUILT_LENGTH": 0.02,
    "SPAN_ID": "MUMUMBMUKLYNSPN001_BU"
  }, {
    "NUMBEROFDUCTS": 6,
    "ROUTETYPE": "OT",
    "ASBUILT_LENGTH": 0.33,
    "SPAN_ID": "MUMUMBMUKLYNSPN001_BU"
  }, {
    "NUMBEROFDUCTS": 7,
    "ROUTETYPE": "CLAMP",
    "ASBUILT_LENGTH": 0.48,
    "SPAN_ID": "MUMUMBMUKLYNSPN001_BU"
  }, {
    "NUMBEROFDUCTS": 5,
    "ROUTETYPE": "OT",
    "ASBUILT_LENGTH": 0.14,
    "SPAN_ID": "MUMUMBMUKLYNSPN001_BU"
  }, {
    "NUMBEROFDUCTS": 8,
    "ROUTETYPE": "OT",
    "ASBUILT_LENGTH": 5.45,
    "SPAN_ID": "MUMUMBMUKLYNSPN001_BU"
  }, {
    "NUMBEROFDUCTS": null,
    "ROUTETYPE": "OT",
    "ASBUILT_LENGTH": 0.23,
    "SPAN_ID": "MUMUMBMUKLYNSPN001_BU"
  }],
  "Table2": [],
  "Table3": [{
    "UMS_GROUP_ASS_BY_NAME": "Construction_Eng",
    "MODIFIED_BY": "HARDIK1.SHAH",
    "MODIFIED_DATE": "2017-11-27T12:07:39",
    "APPROVED_DATE": null,
    "REJECTED_DATE": null
  }, {
    "UMS_GROUP_ASS_BY_NAME": "Construction_Eng",
    "MODIFIED_BY": "HARDIK1.SHAH",
    "MODIFIED_DATE": "2017-11-27T12:07:39",
    "APPROVED_DATE": null,
    "REJECTED_DATE": null
  }, {
    "UMS_GROUP_ASS_BY_NAME": "Construction_Eng",
    "MODIFIED_BY": "HARDIK1.SHAH",
    "MODIFIED_DATE": "2017-11-27T12:07:39",
    "APPROVED_DATE": null,
    "REJECTED_DATE": null
  }, {
    "UMS_GROUP_ASS_BY_NAME": "Construction_Eng",
    "MODIFIED_BY": "HARDIK1.SHAH",
    "MODIFIED_DATE": "2017-11-27T12:07:39",
    "APPROVED_DATE": null,
    "REJECTED_DATE": null
  }, {
    "UMS_GROUP_ASS_BY_NAME": "Construction_Eng",
    "MODIFIED_BY": "HARDIK1.SHAH",
    "MODIFIED_DATE": "2017-11-27T12:07:39",
    "APPROVED_DATE": null,
    "REJECTED_DATE": null
  }, {
    "UMS_GROUP_ASS_BY_NAME": "Construction_Eng",
    "MODIFIED_BY": "HARDIK1.SHAH",
    "MODIFIED_DATE": "2017-11-27T12:07:39",
    "APPROVED_DATE": null,
    "REJECTED_DATE": null
  }, {
    "UMS_GROUP_ASS_BY_NAME": "Construction_Eng",
    "MODIFIED_BY": "HARDIK1.SHAH",
    "MODIFIED_DATE": "2017-11-27T12:07:39",
    "APPROVED_DATE": null,
    "REJECTED_DATE": null
  }]
}
for(count in dataResponse){
 console.log(`[[[[[[[[[[[[[${count}]]]]]]]]]]]]]]`);
 for(item of dataResponse[count]){
    console.log(item);
  }
}
```

You can get easily the value of `dataResponse` with `for-of` and `for-in`.

First, you have to get the `object name` using `for-in`.

Second, you can control the name of tables. (Table, Table1 ...)

`for(item of dataResponse[table])` will return the value of each table.

Comment: Simply posting code is a very poor answer. You should always explain how it works and how to apply it to the question if you are using a different data source. [How to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @ErikPhilips Is it still the poor answer?